# more than one character in rune literal in go

Tags: go

I am the new to go. My problem is get the odd number. But I get this error. I don't know can you explain this what mistake I am done?

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
    var a int 
    fmt.Printf("Enter the number : ")
    fmt.Scanf('%d', &a)

    if a % 2==0{
        fmt.Println(" %d Is even number", a)
    }else{
        fmt.Println( "%d is odd number", a)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `'%d'` to `"%d"`.

In Go *single quotes* are used for [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals).

```
'a'
'ä'
'本'
'\t'
'\000'
'\007'
'\377'
'\x07'
'\xff'
'\u12e4'
'\U00101234'
'\''         // rune literal containing single quote character
'aa'         // illegal: too many characters
'\xa'        // illegal: too few hexadecimal digits
'\0'         // illegal: too few octal digits
'\uDFFF'     // illegal: surrogate half
'\U00110000' // illegal: invalid Unicode code point
```

Double quotes and back quotes are used for [string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

```
`abc`                // same as "abc"
`\n
\n`                  // same as "\\n\n\\n"
"\n"
"\""                 // same as `"`
"Hello, world!\n"
"日本語"
"\u65e5本\U00008a9e"
"\xff\u00FF"
"\uD800"             // illegal: surrogate half
"\U00110000"         // illegal: invalid Unicode code point
```